# What is the best practice when coding math class/functions?

Tags: c++, math

I'm currently implementing some algorithms into an existing program. Long story short,  I created a new class, "Adder". An *Adder* is a member of another class representing the physical object actually doing the calculus , which calls `adder.calc()` with its parameters (merely a list of objects to do the maths on).

To do these maths, I need some parameters, which do not exist outside of the class (but can be *set*, see below). They're neither config parameters nor members of other classes. These parameters are D1 and D2, distances, and three arrays of fixed size: alpha, beta, delta.

I know some of you are more comfortable reading code than reading text so here you go:

```
class Adder
{
public:

  Adder();
  virtual Adder::~Adder();

void set( float d1, float d2 );
  void set( float d1, float d2, int alpha[N_MAX], int beta[N_MAX], int delta[N_MAX] );

  // Snipped prototypes
  float calc( List& ... );
  // ...

  inline float get_d1() { return d1_ ;};
  inline float get_d2() { return d2_ ;};

private:

  float d1_;
  float d2_;

  int alpha_[N_MAX]; // A #define N_MAX is done elsewhere
  int beta_[N_MAX]; 
  int delta_[N_MAX]; 
};
```

Since this object is used as a member of another class, it is declared in a *.h:

```
private:
  Adder adder_;
```

By doing that, I couldn't initialize the arrays (alpha/beta/delta) directly in the constructor ( `int T[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };` ), without having to iterate throughout the three arrays. I thought of putting them in *static const*, but I don't think that's the proper way of solving such problems.

My second guess was to use the constructor to initialize the arrays:

```
Adder::Adder()
{
    int alpha[N_MAX] = { 0, -60, -120, 180, 120,  60 };
    int beta[N_MAX] = { 0,   0,    0,   0,   0,   0 };
    int delta[N_MAX]  = { 0,   0,  180, 180, 180,   0 };

    set( 2.5, 0, alpha, beta, delta );
}

void Adder::set( float d1, float d2 ) {
    if (d1 > 0)
        d1_ = d1;

    if (d2 > 0)
        d2_ = d2;
}

void Adder::set( float d1, float d2, int alpha[N_MAX], int beta[N_MAX], int delta[N_MAX] ) {
    set( d1, d2 );

    for (int i = 0; i < N_MAX; ++i) {
        alpha_[i] = alpha[i];
        beta_[i] = beta[i];
        delta_[i] = delta[i];
    }
}
```

Would it be better to use another function (`init()`) which would initialize the arrays? Or is there a better way of doing that?

Did you see some mistakes or bad practice along the way?

Comment: @Isaac - are the contents of the arrays always the same or do you wish to have the ability to change their contents?

Comment: In the declaration you use `6` instead of `N_MAX`. (And you cannot pass arrays anyway, they'll degrade to pointers.) I don't think arrays can be initialized the way you try to in a constructor. You'll have to assign every member by itself (possibly in a loop).

Comment: @ChrisBD: See the 2nd `Adder::set()`.

Comment: @ChrisBD : I could allow them to be set at compile time, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Sbi : The "6" was a typo. My code compiles and runs under Visual C++ 6 ;) About the function call, should I just pass a reference to the array i want to copy ?

Comment: You could provide both a default constructor that initialises everything to some sensible values and a constructor that takes parameters allowing the user to populate the object on construction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have chosen a very wide subject, so here is a broader answer.

- **Be aware of your surroundings**

Too often I have seen code doing the same thing as elsewhere in the codebase. Make sure that the problem you are trying to solve has not already been solved by your team-mates or predecessors.

- **Try not to reinvent the wheel**

An extension of my previous point.

While everyone should probably write a linked-list or a string class as an exercise, there is no need to write one for production code. You will have access to MFC, OWL, STL, Boost, whatever. If the wheel has already been invented, use it and get on with coding a solution to the real problem!

- **Think about how you are going to test your code**

[Test Driven Development (TDD)](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd) is one way (but not the only way) to ensure that your code is both testable and tested. If you think about testing your code from the beginning, it will be very easy to test. *Then test it!*

- **Write SOLID code**

[The Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)) explains this far better than I could.

- **Ensure your code is readable**

Meaningful identifiers are just the beginning. Unnecessary comments can also detract from readability as can long functions, functions with long argument lists (such as your second setter), etcetera. If you have [coding standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm), stick to them.

- **Use `const` more**

My major gripe with C++ is that things aren't const by default! In your example, your getters should be declared `const` and your setters should have their arguments passed in as `const` (and `const`-reference for the arrays).

- **Ensure your code is maintainable**

Unit tests (as mentioned above) will ensure that the next person to change your code doesn't break your implementation.

- **Ensure your library is usable**

If you follow [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and document your library with unit-tests, programmers using it will have fewer issues.

- **[Refactor](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhatIsRefactoring) mercilessly**

An extension of the previous point. Do everything you can to reduce code duplication. Today I witnessed a bug-fix that had to be executed in fifteen separate places (and was only executed in thirteen of these).

Comment: Thanks for all these ;)
About unit testing, I already coded and ran with success all my tests for the Adder class. My issue here was clarity, reusability and maintenability (which you cover as well). Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 4):

When creating an object I would advise to **always give the user an complete object**, with all member properly initialized. An Init method fails in doing that, making room for a common error, **failing to calling the initializing function in a two phase initialization object.**

To prevent this either make your constructor private and use a builder function or a factory which in turn has access to the init method, or make init private and use it in the constructor. The last advice is generally the same as doing the initialization in the constructor, but it allows several constructors to use the same initializing action.

Comment: I totally agree with your first paragraph: That's what I wanted to avoid with my 2nd method above. A private init() method and set() would be redundant, wouldn't they ?

Comment: @Isaac: If `set()` were implemented in by calling `init()`, who'd care?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.
I would:

1. Set the arrays to a known state by
   using `memset` to clear all values to
   0 (or some other value) within the
   constructor before they are used.
2. Change the constructor to allow the
       passing of array pointers that can
       be used to initialise the arrays to
       some other values.
3. Retain the Set
       function that you have to change the
       values within the arrays and
       ariables that you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'll overload my default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use virtual functions, unless your design actually requires them.
2. In a class that exists primarily to execute one function, that function is canonically named `operator()`. I.e. you'd call yours as `adder_(params)`, not `adder_.calc(params)`.
3. If you're initializing three arrays, it's more efficient to use three for-loops. (cache friendly)

Comment: 1. My teacher always declared his destructor(s) as virtual. I guess I inherited (pun intended :P) from his habits. // 2. Oh ! I never thought of that. I wonder about the readability, though. The C++ I'm working with is very C-oriented (printf, char*, etc.). // 3. That's what I think I lack the most, those kind of optimization. Thanks for the heads up !